# Problem with reading text from Xml with LINQ

Tags: linq

SOLVED.

The Program returns from LINQ search nothing, just 0 (Final=0). I used a debugger, so I think problem is in linq class, because program stops at word 'where'. I don’t understand where is a mistake. Would be very grateful.

```
if (checkLINQ.IsChecked == true)
{
    strategy = new LINQ();
    Final = strategy.Search(_scientist, _filePath);
}
```

```
public class LINQ : IStrategy
 {
  public LINQ() { }

        public ObservableCollection<Scientist> Search(Scientist s, string path)
  {
            ObservableCollection<Scientist> _s = new ObservableCollection<Scientist>();
   var doc = XDocument.Load(path);

var match = (from value in doc.Descendants("Scientist")
         where
            (s.Name == null || s.Name == value.Element("Name")?.Value) &&
         (s.AuthorName == null || s.AuthorName == value.Element("AuthorName")?.Value) &&
         (s.Faculty == null || s.Faculty == value.Element("Faculty")?.Value) &&
         (s.AuthorPosition == null || s.AuthorPosition == value.Element("AuthorPosition")?.Value) &&
         (s.Gender == null || s.Gender == value.Element("Gender")?.Value) &&
         (s.Age == null || == value.Element("Age")?.Value)
         select value).ToList();

   foreach (var obj in match)
   {
    Scientist sc = new Scientist();
    sc.Name = obj.Element("Name")?.Value ?? string.Empty; 
    sc.AuthorName = obj.Element("AuthorName")?.Value ?? string.Empty; 
    sc.Faculty = obj.Element("Faculty")?.Value ?? string.Empty; 
    sc.AuthorPosition = obj.Element("AuthorPosition")?.Value ?? string.Empty; 
    sc.Gender = obj.Element("Gender")?.Value ?? string.Empty; 
    sc.Age = obj.Element("Age")?.Value ?? string.Empty; 
    _s.Add(sc);
            }
   return _s;
  }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your XML. Also, have you checked is there any element that fulfills every filter condition? Thanks.

Comment: Your query works, [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DYQzHX). There is some compilation issue in your `Age` condition. Need to provide more context for example the search criteria to reproduce your issue.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    var result = Search(new Scientist
    {
        Name = "Роботи сучасності", 
        Age = "78"
    }, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yuliia-1102/Lab-xml-linq-/main/Labaratory_2/Scientists.xml");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public static List<Scientist> Search(Scientist s, string path)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(path);

    List<Scientist> Scientists = doc.Descendants("Scientist")
        .Where(x => x.Element("Name")?.Value == s.Name
            || x.Element("AuthorName")?.Value == s.AuthorName
            || x.Element("Faculty")?.Value == s.Faculty
            || x.Element("AuthorPosition")?.Value == s.AuthorPosition
            || x.Element("Gender")?.Value == s.Gender
            || x.Element("Gender")?.Value == s.Gender
            || x.Element("Age")?.Value == s.Age
        )
      .Select(x => new Scientist()
      {
          Name = x.Element("Name")?.Value,
          AuthorName = x.Element("AuthorName")?.Value,
          Faculty = x.Element("Faculty")?.Value,
          AuthorPosition = x.Element("AuthorPosition")?.Value,
          Gender = x.Element("Gender")?.Value,
          Age = x.Element("Age")?.Value
      }).ToList();
    return Scientists;
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Scientist")]
public class Scientist
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AuthorName")]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Faculty")]
    public string Faculty { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AuthorPosition")]
    public string AuthorPosition { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Age")]
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

**Output**

| Name | AuthorName | Faculty | AuthorPosition | Gender | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Математична логіка на практиці | Головченко К.Д. | ФКНК | Доцентка | жінка | 78 |
| Квантові комп'ютери | Гончар Д.І. | ІПСА | Професор | чоловік | 78 |
| Роботи сучасності | Дунай С.Ф. | ІПСА | Професор | чоловік | 80 |